# book suggestion on manifolds

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds

I've to learn differential equations on Manifolds. Can any one please suggest some books/lecture notes for differential equations on Manifolds ?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Partial-Differential-Equations-Applied-Mathematics/dp/0387946543

Comment: M. Taylor has a three books on PDE on manifolds (The above one is the first book). Not sure if that is what you are looking for. (Also there are two books both called "Nonlinear analysis on manifolds", you may want to have a look)

Comment: I think our teacher will teach ODE on manifolds